# What is the span of the following matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

> What is the span of the following row reduced matrix?
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 0&1&0&3&0\\
> 0&0&1&2&0\\       
> 0&0&0&0&1\\
> 0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Explain your answer.

I can't understand how to deal with matrices with one row of 0s and one column of 0s. I thought the parametric equations should be $\{(0, -3d, -2d, d, e)\}$ but I guess I am wrong.

Comment: Is it the span of rows you are looking  for?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for the set of 5x1 matrices you can find once you understand what the parametric equations are

Comment: Note that a $5\times 1$ matrix means five rows, one column.  Your matrix is $4\times 5$.  Perhaps you are interested in the span of the rows of the matrix, which will be a subspace of the $1\times 5$ matrices (i.e. rows of length five).  Elementary row operations leave the space spanned by the rows unchanged, while the space spanned by the columns will generally be changed by elementary *row* operations.

Answer (score 2):

The span of the rows of the matrix is simply obtained by multiplying the three non-zero rows by $a,b,c$ respectively and adding: $(0,a,b,3a+2b,c)$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$.